# Tasmota WebQuery rule not reaching URL despite logging "performs WebQuery" (with Command: Unknown)

Tags: sonoff, tasmota

I have added rule to my tasmota sonoff light switch (typing in console web interface):

```
Rule1 ON POWER2#state==1 DO WebQuery http://192.168.0.106/input.php GET ENDON
```

The output from console:

```
11:51:24 CMD: Rule1 ON POWER2#state==1 DO WebQuery http://192.168.0.106/input.php GET ENDON 11:51:24 RUL: Stored uncompressed, would compress from 77 to 70 (-9%) 
11:51:24 RSL: RESULT = {"Rule1":"ON","Once":"OFF","StopOnError":"OFF","Length":77,"Free":434,"Rules":"ON
POWER2#state==1 DO WebQuery http://192.168.0.106/input.php GET ENDON"}
```

Then I switched the switch manually and noticed in console the corresponding log:

```
11:51:28 RSL: RESULT = {"POWER2":"OFF"}
11:51:28 RSL: POWER2 = OFF
11:51:32 RSL: RESULT = {"POWER2":"ON"}
11:51:32 RSL: POWER2 = ON
11:51:32 RUL: POWER2#STATE==1 performs "WebQuery http://192.168.0.106/input.php GET"
11:51:32 RSL: RESULT = {"Command":"Unknown"}
```

But despite seeing my rule getting fired with `performs "WebQuery http://192.168.0.106/input.php GET"`, my endpoint has not received any HTTP/GET call (which I'm sure about - testing this endpoint from web browser or postman clearly starts a script that also logs some information into file - which is missing when trying to call it from tasmota).

I also get this `RSL: RESULT = {"Command":"Unknown"}` which is strange as I verified the syntax with: https://tasmota.github.io/docs/Commands/#wi-fi

The information tab from Tasmota:

```
Sonoff T1 2CH Module
Lights
Program Version 8.5.1(tasmota)
Build Date & Time   2020-10-02T10:09:47
Core/SDK Version    2_7_4_1/2.2.2-dev(38a443e)
Uptime  0T16:09:38
Flash write Count   4568 at 0xFB000
Boot Count  20
Restart Reason  Software/System restart
Friendly Name 1 Lights
Friendly Name 2 Lights2
     
AP1 SSId (RSSI) Donnie (100%, -41 dBm)
Hostname    tasmota_...
MAC Address ...
IP Address (wifi)   ...
    
Gateway 192.168.0.1
Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0
DNS Server  192.168.0.1
     
MQTT    Disabled
     
Emulation   None
mDNS Discovery  Disabled
     
ESP Chip Id ...
Flash Chip Id   ...
Flash Size  1024kB
Program Flash Size  1024kB
Program Size    596kB
Free Program Space  404kB
Free Memory 26kB
```

Comment: `http://192.168.0.106/input.php` ... does the server log anything?

Comment: `Build Date & Time   2020-10-02T10:09:47` and `Implement WebQuery Command - JVital2013 committed on 24 Sep 2021` seems like a hint.

Answer (score 1):

The WebQuery command was added in [v10.0.0 Norman](https://github.com/arendst/Tasmota/releases/tag/v10.0.0) of Tasmota.

You are running version 8.5.1.

Apparently Tasmota just records the command to execute without trying to interpret it at configuration time, but only when it is actually triggered, at which point you get the "Command Unknown".

NB: HTTPS support was added in v10.1.0 Noelle, so if you plan on using HTTPS you'll need at least that version.

The latest version of Tasmota is v11.1.0.

Also note that it looks like you need there are breaking changes between 8.5.1 and those versions, and you may also need to upgrade to 9.1 before upgrading to the latest version, see the release notes for details.